# Why are my arrays not working on this C program?

Tags: arrays, c

So I have to create a program in which the user can input a list of integers, and then the program will evaluate if the first half of the list is the same as the other half (so a list like 1 2 3 1 2 3 would produce true), and if the list contains an odd number of characters then just print an error message.

So far I have been able to get the user input as an array, and then break that big array into two smaller arrays, which represent the two halves of the whole list. My professor specified that the largest list the program is supposed to handle is 100 characters long, so I declared an array of 100 elements to store the initial list, and if the list is smaller than that, then just use however many integers the user inputs.

My plan was then to declare two arrays of length 50 to represent the biggest each of the halves of the list can be. However, when I declare the three arrays (the 100 long array for the list, and the two 50 long arrays for the halves) my program just doesn't work. It's supposed to prompt an user to enter a list, and it works if and only if I declare the first array to be 100 integers long, and if the other two are declared to be 10 integers long. Anything other than that will result in the program skipping the input part and just finishing abruptly without doing what it is supposed to.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int getList(int* list);
void checkList();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    checkList();
    return 0;
    }
    

int getList(int* list) {              
    int input;
    int count;
    int i = 0;
    
    printf("Enter the list you want to evaluate. When you're done, enter 0 twice:\n");
    
    while(input != 0 && count < 100) { //the program will prompt the user to enter numbers as long as 0 is not entered
        scanf("%d\n", &input);
        if (input == 0) {
            printf("Done! Now the program will evaluate the list\n");
        }
        else {
            list[i] = input;
            i++;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void checkList() {  
    int list[100]; //representing the biggest the list can ever be
    int listA[10]; //should be 50 each, but as stated above, it won't work
    int listB[10];
    int count;
    int a = getList(list);
    printf("%d\n", a); //for this part I was just printing the count variable from the method above, to see if it was returning it properly
    if (a % 2 == 0) { //checking if the number of elements of the list is odd or even
        int i;
    for (i = 0; i < a / 2; i++) {
        listA[i] = list[i];
        printf("%d ", listA[i]);
        count++;
    }
    int j;
    for (j = count; j < (a / 2) + count; j++) {
        listB[j] = list[j];
        printf("%d ", listB[j]);
    }
    }
    else {
        printf("The list entered contains an odd number of elements and therefore cannot be evaluated\n");
    }   
}
```

(On a side note, I can't get the program to stop when the user enters a single 0 but instead it will only stop if the user enters two 0's, why's that?)

Any idea of what might be wrong with my program? Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that your code can't be compiled as it — it is not an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name
The headers and global declarations are missing.  However, in `checkList()`, what is `count` initialized to before the first loop?

Comment: The uninitialized `count` is almost certainly the problem, and the array sizes are irrelevant.

Comment: I edited the code so it can be compiled. count is supposed to start at 0 for both, but I tried to initialize them to see if that was the issue and it did nothing

Comment: Is there a reason why you need both `i` and `count` in `getList()`? They both increment together.

Comment: Your second loop in `checkList()` is not assigning values to `listB[0] .. listB[a/2]`.  You need one variable to index into `list` starting at `a/2` (that's `j`); you need another to index into `listB` starting at 0.  Or use `listB[j - a/2]`, I suppose.

Comment: I followed Barmar's advice and deleted `count` as a variable, and made getList() return `i` instead, and it all worked! I have no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is because the count variable is uninitiated. Even if that is not the direct cause, it will still prevent your program from working. When you have an uninitialized variable, seemingly ramdom changes to other parts of the program can cause it to fail. In your case, it seems like changing the sizes of values placed on the stack (10 vs 50) elements causes the count variable in getList to be greater than 100, meaning that the while loop will not run (alternatively, it could initialize input to 0).

Answer (score 0):

I see at least four issues.

**First**: count should be initialized inside getList and inside checkList

**Second**:

```
if (a % 2 == 0) { //checking if the number of elements of the list is odd or even
        int i;
for (i = 0; i < a / 2; i++) {
```

If the number a is odd, you won't declare the variable i, but you will still enter the for loops using i. Won't like it.

**Third**: You check for a to be odd before declaring i, but not for j. I guess you just forgot to return from checkList() if a is odd.

**Fourth**: the variables i and count in getList() are kinda redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `getList` function. Sending array name to a pointer parameter is a bit confusing. I recommend you not to mix array and pointers together in your code.

Also, `scanf("%d", &input);` I did not use new line character and I can end the list just with one zero.

Here is the correct program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
checkList();
return 0;
}




void checkList() {  
int list[100]; //representing the biggest the list can ever be
int listA[10]; //should be 50 each, but as stated above, it won't work
int listB[10];
int count;
int input;

int i = 0;

printf("Enter the list you want to evaluate. When you're done, enter 0 twice:\n");

while(input != 0 && count < 100) { //the program will prompt the user to enter numbers 
as long as 0 is not entered
    scanf("%d", &input);
    if (input == 0) {
        printf("Done! Now the program will evaluate the list\n");
    }
    else {
        list[i] = input;
        i++;
        count++;
    }
}

printf("length of list %d\n", count); //for this part I was just printing the count 
variable from the method above, to see if it was returning it properly
if (count % 2 == 0) { //checking if the number of elements of the list is odd or even
int a;
a=count;
count=0;
for (i = 0; i < a / 2; i++) {
    listA[i] = list[i];
    printf("%d ", listA[i]);
    count++;
}
int j;
for (j = count; j < (a / 2) + count; j++) {
    listB[j] = list[j];
    printf("%d ", listB[j]);
}
}
else {
    printf("The list entered contains an odd number of elements and therefore cannot 
be evaluated\n");
}   
}
```

Comment: Hi, I wouldn't have used another function either, but the assignment requirements said that we needed two functions, one for accepting the list and another one for checking if they were equal. Thanks for your help though and I was able to fix the double 0 thing